# getpwent_r and alpine musl libc

Tags: alpine-linux, musl

I am trying to compile an app with a dependency on a shared object with a single call to `getpwent_r()` (I didn't write the lib). As far as I can tell, `getpwent_r()` is a glibc extension, and not POSIX compliant.

Any way to get that functionality, short of an alternate lib so (which is impossible as a lot of core functionality is in that lib) or trying to get the so recompiled using `getpwent()`?